# Edit Email Alert message before send

Tags: email-alert

Is there a way to edit the email message that is being sent as Email Alert (just before sending, from apex)? I would like to add some special text from apex code, but also wouldn't like to create the whole email from scratch.

Comment: You can just write the dynamic message you want into some (hidden if needed) field on the object where you are sending the email alert from, and then add that merge field into your email template.

Comment: What's the reason of downvote?
@RobinDeBondt please write your comment as an answer if you want, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write the dynamic message you want into some (hidden if needed) field on the object where you are sending the email alert from, and then add that merge field into your email template.